# Existence of isometrical isomorphism between isomorphic finite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, isometry

I am currently studying the proof of the following theorem:

> Every finite dimensional normed vector space is complete, and every finite dimensional subspace of a normed vector space is closed.

The proof begins with an isometric isomorphism between the finite dimensional vector space $X$ with $K^n$ (as always $K=\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$).

It is clear that we have an isomorphism $T: X\to K^n$. But I do not see why we also get an isometry.

I think we can get a norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ on $K^n$ by constructing it with regards to the norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $X$ like this:

When $x_1,\dotso, x_n$ is a basis of $X$, and $e_1,\dotso, e_n$ is a basis of $K^n$, we get an isomorphism by mapping basis elements to basis elements.

If we then construct the norm $\|\cdot\|_1: K^n\to [0,\infty)$, by letting $\|e_i\|_1=\|x_i\|$ if I see it correctly this actually yields a norm, which is in some sense "induced" by the norm of $X$.

Can you confirm this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $E$ and $F$ are vector spaces, $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $F$, and $T \colon E \to F$ is an injective linear map, then $\|x\|_T := \|Tx\|$ for each $x \in E$ defines a norm $\|\cdot\|_T$ on $E$. In your case, consider the norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $X$, and a linear isomorphism $\phi \colon K^n \to X$. If you define $x_i := \phi(e_i)$, then the norm $\|\cdot\|_\phi$ on $K^n$ is your $\|\cdot\|_1$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, that was basically my take on it. Maybe I were too sloppy in communicating it above, as the $e_i$ are supposed to be the image of the $x_i$ under the linear map.